# How to plot the amplitude of audio file with c++?

Tags: c++, qt, audio, plot, amplitude

I'm trying to create a program, using Qt (c++), which can plot the amplitude  Signal (plot like audacity but dynamic waveform) when I playback  an audio file (.wav, .mp3) using `QAudiooutput` and `QIODevice`.

What I've done:
 with `QAudioouput` I can play the any audio file, with qwtplot I can plot any signal in 2D, in this case, x-axis will be time and y-axis will be the amplitude.

Now, my problem is how  to get the amplitude for each second (time)?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, can you be more precise please ? You want to compute an average amplitute value each second ?

Comment: my graph is amplitude=f(t), and time is a second that means each time (s) correspond to an amplitude. Actually I want to plot signal like audacity but dynamic waveform

Comment: What is a "dynamic waveform"? Do you perhaps mean an audio stream?

Answer (score 0):

The normal, uncompressed representation of audio is just its amplitude as a function of time. `.wav` files are ordinarily uncompressed, so a mono `.WAV` file is really the simplest of audio files: just a header followed by a series of amplitudes.

Note that digital audio has a sampling rate. E.g. a 32 kHz sample rate means that your WAV file has 32000 amplitudes per second. If it only had one, you couldn't hear it ! (<20 Hz). You can see this in Audacity; you can zoom in quite a bit on the waveform.