# Finding the current volume level of the speaker output in Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, audio

EDITED: I'm trying to write a sort of audio visualizer and I need to get the current volume of the sound being sent to the speakers. I need the actual volume of the sound, not just the master volume of the device. I've been trying to do it using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/loopback-recording) but I'm unsure how to implement it. Having called the [IAudioCaptureClient::GetBuffer()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audioclient/nf-audioclient-iaudiocaptureclient-getbuffer#remarks) method, I don't know how to use the resulting data packet to find what I need. The audio is 2 channel, 32 bits per sample. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The Windows audio subsystem has changed dramatically since Windows XP. Check out the EndpointVolume API.

Answer (score 1):

> Starting with Windows 7, the existing APIs have been improved and new
>   APIs have been added to support new scenarios. The stream and session
>   management APIs have been improved so that the application can now
>   enumerate and get extended control over the audio session. By using
>   the new APIs, the application can implement a custom stream
>   attenuation experience. New device-related APIs provide access to the
>   driver properties of the endpoint devices.

Refer: [Core Audio APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/core-audio-apis-in-windows-vista?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Here is a simple demo for reference:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mmeapi.h>
#include <mmdeviceapi.h> 
#include <endpointvolume.h>
#include <audioclient.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"Winmm.lib")

bool GetVolumeLevel()
{
    HRESULT hr;
    IMMDeviceEnumerator* pDeviceEnumerator = 0;
    IMMDevice* pDevice = 0;
    IAudioEndpointVolume* pAudioEndpointVolume = 0;

    try {
        hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator), NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator), (void**)&pDeviceEnumerator);
        if (FAILED(hr)) throw "CoCreateInstance";
        hr = pDeviceEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender, eMultimedia, &pDevice);
        if (FAILED(hr)) throw "GetDefaultAudioEndpoint";
        hr = pDevice->Activate(__uuidof(IAudioEndpointVolume), CLSCTX_ALL, NULL, (void**)&pAudioEndpointVolume);
        if (FAILED(hr)) throw "pDevice->Active";

        float fVolume;

        hr = pAudioEndpointVolume->GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(&fVolume);
        printf("%lf", fVolume);
        if (FAILED(hr)) throw "SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar";

        pAudioEndpointVolume->Release();
        pDevice->Release();
        pDeviceEnumerator->Release();
            return true;
    }
    catch (...) {
        if (pAudioEndpointVolume) pAudioEndpointVolume->Release();
        if (pDevice) pDevice->Release();
        if (pDeviceEnumerator) pDeviceEnumerator->Release();
        throw;
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    CoInitialize(0);
    try {
        GetVolumeLevel();

    }
    catch (...) {
        //err handle..
    }
    CoUninitialize();

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

It will return to the volume level of the current speaker.

You can focus on this api: [IAudioEndpointVolume::GetMasterVolumeLevelScal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/endpointvolume/nf-endpointvolume-iaudioendpointvolume-getmastervolumelevelscalar)

> The GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar method gets the master volume level of
>   the audio stream that enters or leaves the audio endpoint device. The
>   volume level is expressed as a normalized, audio-tapered value in the
>   range from 0.0 to 1.0.

Comment: Mixing raw pointers and C++ exception handling will inevitably make your code unmaintainable. Either use RAII, or just don't throw exceptions to model control flow. Note in particular, that you're printing the volume, regardless of whether the call to retrieve it succeeded or not.

Comment: This gets the master volume. I need to get the actual amplitude of the sound being sent to the speakers. I've found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/loopback-recording but am having trouble implementing it for my purpose.

Comment: @CameronNeil You can edit question or post a new question to show the details of the problems you encounter. I believe there will be many community members willing to help you solve them.

Comment: @CameronNeil The normal, uncompressed representation of audio is just its amplitude as a function of time. .wav files are ordinarily uncompressed, so a mono .WAV file is really the simplest of audio files: just a header followed by a series of amplitudes. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24995587/11128312). Do you want to get an audio amplitude similar to waveform?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you found it for yourself.
I would start here with the peakmeter info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/peak-meters